# derivative of an integral with respect to its upper limit

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I am currently asking myself whether I did everything correctly when differentiating an integral with respect to its upper limit. I need the solution of this differentiation for further calculations in R and want to make sure the results I get out of my routine are not wrong.

Let $F(0)=G(0)=0$, Is it correct that

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{x=0}^{x=t}\int_{u=0}^{u=x}\,\mathrm dF(u)\,\mathrm dG(x) = G'(t)\int_{u=0}^{u=t}\,\mathrm dF(u) $$

provide $G'(t)$ exists?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed it is true. It can be broken down further as shown. $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{x=0}^{x=t}\int_{u=0}^{u=x}\,\mathrm dF(u)\,\mathrm dG(x) =\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{u=0}^{u=x}\,\mathrm dF(u) \,G'(x)\,\mathrm dx = G'(t)\int_{u=0}^{u=t}\,\mathrm dF(u)\\= G'(t)\int_{u=0}^{u=t}\,\mathrm dF(u)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, so then there should be some error in my optimization routine which I have to get rid of. Sometimes I should trust my math skills more than my programming ones :)

Comment: Dumb question: how do you know $F'(u)$ exists?

Comment: @BCLC you don't, that step can be avoided actually, the proof still holds (you would have $\mathrm dF(u)$ throughout

Comment: BCLC thanks for the comment, I should have mentioned it exists by assumption. But else it's like John Doe mentioned.